# Prove the running time of the expression

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Im having some issue in proving this analysis problem

My answer is coming O(n^3)

Prove that the running time of `T(n)=n^3+20n+1` is `(O(n^4))`

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that `T(n) = n^3 + 20*n + 1` is `O(n^4)`, just apply the definition of big-O.

We need to show that there exist positive constant `M > 0` and number `N` such that

`|T(n) / n^4| < M` for all `n > N`

Now, take `M = 3` and `N = 3`. Then, for any `n > N` we have `|T(n) / n^4| = |(n^3 + 20*n + 1) / n^4| = |1 / n + 20 / n^3 + 1 / n^4| < |1/3 + 20/27 + 1/81| < |1 + 1 + 1| = 3 = M`. QED

It is true that the most significant term in `T(n)` as n goes to infinity is `n^3` but it doesn't deny the fact that `T(n)` is `O(n^4)`. Using similar argument one can show that `T(n)` is `O(n^3)` (in fact, `T(n)` is big-theta of `n^3` which is stronger than big-O of `n^3`).